# Required imports to execute qrcode?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, helios

am trying to encode the values given in an Text View into an QR code at the click of a button.
i downloaded zing 1.6.zip and don't know which one to import among all the folders for my process

i try with this website http://www.onbarcode.com/products/android_barcode/barcodes/qrcode.html

but nothing went good with it, what class files i need to import in order to execute the above code

Comment: ZXing 1.6 is really old. Use 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the OnBarcode.AndroidBarcode.jar file to the libs directory of your android project.

Then make sure you add it to your classpath. If you're in eclipse, you can paste the file in the libs directory. Then right click it -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path.

At that point you can start using it:

```
QRCode barcode = new QRCode();
```

And again, in eclipse, as long as you have the jar file on your build path, can do a ctrl+shift+O to fix imports and pull in the correct class imports.